# Why is char the only type to be read into an array form with scanf?

Tags: c

Why can you read a string of chars by filling an array with a simple:

```
char test[100];
scanf("%s", test);
```

While you can't get the same behaviour for, say, int:

```
int test2[100];
scanf("%d", test2);
```

Why is that so? Why was it decided that by using the latter you don't get, say, an array with each digit in a different cell?

Comment: What if you wanted to input like, each 2 digits inside? What would be the deterministic factor there..? It's not like base 10 digits have any significance to computers anyway.

Comment: Note: `scanf("%s", test);` more precisely does _not_ read a string, but stores what it does read as a string.  It 1st scans in leading white-space and discards them.  Then it reads and saves in non-white-space `char` until a white-space, IO error of EOF condition occurs. Then it appends a '\0'.  In a rare situation, should it _read_ a '\0', it will gleefully save that _and continue_ as '\0' is not a white-space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%s` format is special because of the specific way of representing strings in C as a null-terminated sequence of characters placed at consecutive memory addresses. This representation happens to coincide with the representation of character arrays, but the primary driving force behind the `%s` format specifier are C strings, not character arrays.

Note that when you read a string into a `char` array of fixed size with `scanf` functions, you should tell the function how much memory you have allocated to avoid buffer overruns:

```
char test[100];
scanf("%99s", test);
//      ^^
// Minus one for the null terminator
```